# node.js modbus RTU via TCP (RTU over TCP)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, modbus

I'm trying to read Holding registers from server.
Slave serves data in protocol modbus RTU via TCP.
In Python i am using "framer" :

```
client = IW_ModbusClient(ini['server_ip'], port=ini['server_port'], framer=IW_ModbusFramer)
```

But I can't find appropriate solution in javascript.
I tried most popular modbus libraries in npm, but most of them reading data just in RTU or TCP (not RTU via TCP):

- modbus-serial
- jsmodbus
- ModbusJS

I found one library in npm but it's seems that it was working for older nodejs versions. and I can't install it:

- modbus-rtu-tcp

Comment: RTU over TCP is not a standard protocol. Two solutions, 1-create your own drive that sends the RTU protocol bytes, CRC included, over a TCP connection. 2-Install a Modbus TCP to RTU hardware gateway

Answer (score 0):

On modbus rtu and tcp data frames are different.

If you want to send rtu data via tcp need to know data frames, how to work tcp and serial communication and code some functions.

For example;

[TCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfcOm.png)
[RTU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5SRe.png)